# JavaScript slice method?

Tags: javascript

I want to slice elements of one array into a new left and right array.  I am stuck on how to start this.

Comment: Three W3 Schools answers within a minute. What is wrong with this world? `:)`

Comment: let's not bring name of this site here :)

Comment: But let's bring this name here: [W3 Fools](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this array:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

If you want to split the array so that the first 4 items go to the left array and the rest to the right array, then do this:

```
var leftArr = arr.slice(0, 4);
```

and

```
var rightArr = arr.slice(4);
```

You can make a function that returns those two arrays based on the split-position:

```
function splitArr(arr, i) {
    return [ arr.slice(0, i), arr.slice(i) ];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to start with the "[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)" method.  Note that it returns a NEW array without changing the old array, so you'll want to go back and mutate the old array as well.

For instance:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5],
    b = a.slice(3);

a.length = 3;
// a is now [1,2,3]
// b is now [4,5]
```

Comment: you note that the original array won't change, but then in your example you show it changed???

Comment: Yep. It's three lines, try it yourself. =)

Comment: Line three (a.length = 3) changes the original array.

Comment: ahh, you're manually setting the length, missed that, thought you were saying that a.length was 3.

Answer (score 2):

umm.....  have you looked at [`.slice()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) ?

```
new_array = your_array.slice( start_index , end_index );
```

This creates a completely new array, not a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **splice**.

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6];

var b=a.splice(3,a.length);


now a= [1,2,3]
and b=[4,5,6]
```

Comment: Just `var b = a.splice(3);` is fine too. The second argument is not needed.

Comment: @Šime Vidas- that's what I thought, until I tried it in IE. IE (before version 9) does nothing to the array and returns an empty array, without the second argument.

Comment: You're right. This is odd. [Microsoft's own reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkcsy6fe(v=vs.85).aspx) states that the second argument is optional. Btw, I also checked the old ECMAScript spec (ES3 from 1999.) - same thing. This feature is old, I have no idea why Microsoft didn't implement it until IE9.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp :

Syntax :

```
array.slice(start, end)
```

Example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  document.write(fruits.slice(0,1) + "<br />");
  document.write(fruits.slice(1) + "<br />");
  document.write(fruits.slice(-2) + "<br />");
  document.write(fruits);
</script>
```

Output :

```
Banana
Orange,Apple,Mango
Apple,Mango
Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.write(fruits.slice(0,1) + "<br />"); //Banana
document.write(fruits.slice(1) + "<br />"); //Orange,Apple,Mango
document.write(fruits.slice(-2) + "<br />"); //Apple,Mango
document.write(fruits); //Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

(Reference from w3schools):
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_slice_array