# array.slice(1, 1) is giving me an empty array

Tags: arrays, slice

Why does `array.slice(1, 1)/array.slice(2, 2)` returns an empty array, while the original array is not empty?

```
array = ['ele1', 'ele2', 'ele3', 'ele4', 'ele5', 'ele6', 'ele7', 'ele8', 'ele9', 'ele10’];
```

Comment: @Ruthvik Yedla, please clarify the question. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

> The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start
>   argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.

This is why you receive an empty output.

For the given example, you can try:

`fruits.slice(1);`

Because second argument is omitted, all elements after this one will be extracted through the end of the sequence.

If you write `fruit.slice(1,1)`, there is nothing to return.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = ["Banana", " Orange", " Lemon", " Apple", " Mango"];
  var citrus = fruits.slice(1);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = citrus;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Give it a try:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYXpjj

Check also:
[Array.slice on array with one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938712/array-slice-on-array-with-one-element)
and
[JavaScript slice method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526112/javascript-slice-method)

Answer (score 0):

*array.slice(1,1)* will always give you empty because

> The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start
>   argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.

**Explanation**

*array.slice(1,1)*  will returns another array which will start from 1 and it will not include the the given end argument which is in this case is 1 ( i.e. if you end argument is 2 then it will give only one element starting from 1 )